# How to remove certain files from global .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Whenever I push my code to Github, the crucial file `.angular-cli.json` is being filtered out from my `git add *` files.

So whenever I clone a repo of a new Angular 4 project I get an error, because `.angular-cli.json` is missing, and when trying to `ng serve` I get an error.

How do I remove this default settings where `.angular-cli.json` is being filtered out?

Is there a global `.gitignore` configuration?

Comment: The problem is not that the file is ignored somehow but that `*` does not match it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
git add .
```

instead of

```
git add *
```

The latter adds all files except the ones that begins with a dot. Note that `*` is not part of Git, it's a regex that's *interpreted by your shell*.

And when you use `git add .`, since `.` is your current directory, Git will add all files that are under this directory.

Comment: `*` is not interpreted by the shell if you use the normal command prompt on Windows.